# pst-asr produces all nodes on top of each other in xelatex

Tags: xetex, pstricks, linguistics, pst-asr

I was trying to recompile an old handout that used to work, but ran into the following issue, which is shown in the minimal example below (taken from the pst-asr documentation examples):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr}

\begin{document}
   \asr logwhin\endasr
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: MWE]

It seems that all of the segments are piled one on top of the other.

Other pstricks stuff seems to work fine for the most part in my current setup.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I fail to reproduce the issue on my updated TeXLive2019 installation. That is, there is a chance that updating your TeX installation may fix the issue. However, in general it is, unfortunately, true that the outputs produced by `latex` and then `dvipdf` on the one hand and `xelatex` can differ for `pstricks` stuff.

Comment: I am able to reproduce using the current TexLive 2020 in Debian sid.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases nodes do not work with `xelatex`. In such a case use the sequence `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`  or use `pdflatex` with package `auto-pst-pdf` and running `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-asr}

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
    \asr logwhin\endasr
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

However, in your simple case nodes are not used, so you should provide the current file version with `\listfiles` at first line in your code:

```
    \listfiles
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pst-asr}
    \begin{document}
        \asr logwhin\endasr
    \end{document}

For an up-to-date TeX distribution you should get something like this:

 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pst-asr.sty    2011/04/20 v1.6 LaTex wrapper pst-asr.tex (JF)
pstricks.sty    2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02b unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks.pro    2018/11/14 v. 1.29, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-algparser.pro    2011/10/31 v. 0.04, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-tools.pro    2012/01/01 v. 0.02, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pst-dots.pro    2006/12/19 v. 2.00, PostScript prologue file (hv)
pstricks-xetex.def
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
```

If you have the same versions, then the only problem can be the config file `dvipdfmx.cfg` which is saved in the directory `.../dvipdfmx/`. Search for a line like

```
D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 [...]
```

Change it to

```
D  "rungs -q -dNOSAFER  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 [...]
```

With `-dNOSAFER` ghostscript can load external files which is important for PSTricks.

Comment: I'm getting this issue on Debian sid's current version of TexLive 2020 (with `pstricks.tex    2020/09/18 v3.01`).  I updated the line in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg` (which uses `gs` instead of `rungs`) as suggested, and had no change in behaviour.

Comment: I note that pstricks seems to include the following file: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg` (`446 2017-04-19 11:40:55Z`).  It doesn't seem to include any similar lines, but it is loaded on compile, and I wonder if it might somehow be relevant here...

Comment: No chance here: It does not work with `xelatex`

Comment: It used to work with xelatex.  A document I compiled a couple years ago is beautiful; the same source compiled with the same `Makefile` now has this problem.  Something has changed with xelatex compatibility.

Comment: Things also come out nicely using xelatex on Overleaf, even with TexLive 2020, which is interesting considering that's what I have locally and things don't come out nicely.

Comment: there were some changes in the xdvipdfmx file, which may be the problem ...

Comment: I presume this is reportable, then.  Should it be reported to XeLaTeX maintainers, TeXLive maintainers, or pstricks maintainers?  Alternatively, should pst-asr be considered out of date now, and in need of updating?

Comment: `xdvipdfmx` does _not_ support the full PostScript code. However, feel free to write to the  maintainers of `dvipdfm`